# Is it possible to add or exclude certain files for Haskell Stack --file-watch, and how?

Tags: git, haskell, haskell-stack

The title is basically the whole question.

My specific use cases are these:

1. I want to exclude `.git/index` from the list, as I don't want to rebuild every time I stage something; and
2. I want to include files from `.git/refs/heads` in order to rebuild automatically after a commit.

---

To clarify, in response to some very sensible comments:

I believe the reason that `.git/index` is being monitored may because of my use of the GitHash module. However, I believe the only relevant activities affecting the data coming from that are (a) saving a file (which turns on the dirty flag); and (b) committing, which moves `HEAD` to a new hash.

Comment: I'm not sure  about  point 1, but point 2 might  be achieved with git hooks instead, to force a  build  every time  you commit.

Comment: Changes into the `.git` folder do not trigger a rebuild, I just tested (staging a file, committing, etc.). However modifying files listed under `extra-source-files` does trigger a rebuild. However I just tried adding `.git/refs/heads` to it, but it doesn't trigger a build on commit. That being said, why would you want that? Committing has no impact on the code, so I don't see the benefit of triggering a build at that moment... Can you tell us more about the "why"?

Comment: @Sir4ur0n : Thanks for your comment; much appreciated. I've added a bit more background to clarify.

Comment: Ah, I see, this is most definitely linked to GitHash then. I guess your best shot is asking on https://github.com/snoyberg/githash you are much more likely to get a relevant answer there :D Good luck and please let us know on Stackoverflow if there is a solution ;)